# How to reference a javascript variable to be the value of the props of a component?

Tags: reactjs

I created a component named CheckboxFilter. I want to use it and pass props to it. The value of the props is a javascript variable :

```
const FilterWrapper = ({ component, filterLabel, requiredField, ...others }) => {
  let { filterLabels } = others;
  let checkboxes = [];
  if (Array.isArray(filterLabels) && filterLabels.length > 0) {
    filterLabels.forEach(function(label) {
      checkboxes.push(<CheckboxFilter text=   />); // how to pass the variable label here ?
    });
  }
  ...
};
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess it should work with curly braces.

```html
<CheckboxFilter text={label} />
```